# Aura:iteration is not working in my Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Problem facing:attribute products & prodVersion contains values. If I Used in aura:iteration values will not appear

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="products" type="List"/>
 <aura:attribute name="prodVersion" type="List"/>

  <aura:iteration var="p" items="{!v.products}"> 
                       <p>{!p}</p>  //values will not apear
                    </aura:iteration>
```

Controller:

```
getProductDetails:function(component){
    var Category = [];
    var allProducts = [];
    var prodVersions = [];
    var sortedProdVersions = [];
    var articleId = component.get("v.urlName"); 
    var action = component.get("c.getArticleProducts");
    action.setParams({
        "documentId": articleId
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {               
            var article = response.getReturnValue();
            //alert('article lenght:'+article.length+'article'+JSON.stringify(article));
            for(var i=0;i<article.length;i++){
                if(article[i].Product__r.Name!='' && article[i].Product__r.Name!=null && typeof article[i].Product__r.Name!='undefined'){
                    if( /\d/.test(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','))){

                        prodVersions.push(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        allProducts.push(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','));

                    }
                }

            }  //for loop end here
            prodVersions.sort(
                (a,b) => {
                    let av = Number(a.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)[0]), bv = Number(b.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/));
                    return bv - av; // inverted subtraction to sort largest->smallest
                }
            );
            //prodVersions  -has value & allProducts-has value
            component.set("v.prodVersion", prodVersions);
            component.set("v.products",allProducts);
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

server side:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static  List<Related_KM_Product__c> getArticleProducts(String documentId) {
    String query;
    String myTestString =documentId;
    List<Related_KM_Product__c> PRList ;
    if(documentId != null){
        query ='select id,DocumentID__c,Name,Product__c,Product__r.Name,Product_Version__c,Product_Version__r.Name from Related_KM_Product__c where DocumentID__c = :myTestString';
     }
     PRList=Database.query(query);
    system.debug('PRList>>>>'+PRList);
      if(!PRList.isEmpty()){
      return PRList;
      }else{
          return NULL;
      }

}
```

In Javascript side,If I pass Like below.then aura:iteration will work

```
            component.set("v.prodVersion", prodVersions[0]);
            component.set("v.products",allProducts[0]);
```

If I pass it like this it will not work:

```
            component.set("v.prodVersion", prodVersions);
            component.set("v.products",allProducts);
```

I have modified aura:attribute to string & also modified to Related_KM_Product__c[].But aura:itertaion isnot working

Comment: Try to debug your code to find the step which fails. Simply add console.log() within LC and System.debug() within APEX controller and you will get the line of code which behaves in an undesirable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
allProducts.push(article[i].Product__r.Name.split(','));
```

you are adding the array that `split` creates as an element of your `allProducts` array. So you have an array of arrays, meaning this is more likely to work:

```
<aura:iteration var="product" items="{!v.products}">
    <aura:iteration var="part" items="{!product}"> 
        <p>{!part}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```